# How to change the default "fullscreen" monitor?

Tags: nvidia, multi-monitor, games

I have to monitors, one attached to my Nvidia graphics card using HDMI, the other one using VGA (using a DVI-VGA adapter). Most fullscreen games (that even recognizes that there are two monitors) uses the secondary monitor. The primary monitor is correctly set when I check from nvidia-settings, `xrandr` or KDE system settings.

My current workaround is to simply disable monitor 2 when playing a game but that's not satisfiying. How can I effectively set the primary screen?

Comment: Does setting the primary with `xrandr` help?

Comment: `xrandr` already reports that it is. I guess it gets the info from the same source as the other tools.

Comment: Could this depend on the position of the mouse pointer at the time the application goes fullscreen?

Comment: Depends on the game and its implementation, I guess. There are other things, like the gnome-panel ... mate-panel these days ... which defines that monitor as primary which is reported first _by the graphics board_. Stupid and wrong implementation, but true. Maybe your games support some command line arguments for placement and/or monitor selection?

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't been able to actually keep both screens enabled, I can at least map games to the correct screen. What I did was change the 'metamode' line in `xorg.conf`:

```
Option         "metamodes" "CRT: 1280x1024 +1920+180, DFP: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP: 1920x1200, CRT: NULL"
```

I'm not entirely sure what the first part does, it was autogenerated by `nvidia-settings`. The second part however instructs the driver to realize a request for 1920x1200 resolution -- the native resolution of my primary screen, `DFP` -- by disabling the secondary one (`CRT`).

Those games that were well-behaved to begin with never actually changed the resolution to begin with but instead created a full-screen sized borderless window and placed it on the primary screen.

EDIT: This doesn't work as well as I thought, the mode isn't switched back properly later.